# Literature recommendation subordinator models

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance-mathematics, stochastic-volatility

I'm looking for relevant papers covering subordinator models for stock price modelling. I have alreay read the paper 'A Subordinated Stochastic Process Model with Finite Variance for Speculative Prices' by Peter Clark (https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913889?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: A more recent paper along this line is H. Geman: Order flow, transaction clock, and normality of asset returns, JF Dec. 2002.

Comment: No one else knows any papers?